# Getting a 'Undefined' list in JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, api, kimono

The JSON I'm requesting is an array within an array (I think) and looks like this:

```
"results": {
"collection1": [
  {
    "Inches": "1\"",
    "Resort": "Keystone",
    "index": 1,
    "url": "http://extras.denverpost.com/skireport/colorado/recentsnow.html"
  },
  {
    "Inches": "0\"",
    "Resort": "Breckenridge",
    "index": 2,
    "url": "http://extras.denverpost.com/skireport/colorado/recentsnow.html"
  },
  {
    "Inches": "0\"",
    "Resort": "Telluride",
    "index": 3,
    "url": "http://extras.denverpost.com/skireport/colorado/recentsnow.html"
  },
```

I am trying to display this information in a list, but I get an 'Undefined' result list with the following JQuery:

```
   $.ajax({
   url:"www.kimonolabs.com/api/5qtdkod0apikey=z6vewKq5SXBcF6Q6L17sQEJ8gaYMou0C",
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: "jsonp",
  'success': function (response) {

  $(".panel-heading").html(response.name);
  //Puts the API name into the panel heading

  var collection = response.results.collection1;
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){


     $(".list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + 
     collection[i].resort.inches + '</li>');
   //when I just try to bring in either resort or inches I get an 'undefined' list-- when I try to add both (e.g resort.inches) I don't get any results
      }
     }
   });
```

What's the best way to define the resort and inches data and display it in the "list-group-item" list.  Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6w0sdctg/

Comment: Based on the object structure you posted, `collection[i].resort.inches` is undefined. You could do `collection[i].Resort` or `collection[i].Inches`. But `collection[i].Resort` is not an object containing a property called `inches`.

Comment: Are you sure that web service supports JSONP?

Comment: Did you copy the URL correctly in the question? There should be `?` before `apikey=`/

Comment: When I run your API request I get this "{"error":"Gone","message":"Sorry! We only provide access to the last 30 days of your data. If you'd like longer retention, please contact us at support@kimonolabs.com."}" - You need to run the crawl again.

Comment: The crawls should be set up to run daily... i just ran it again, so it should work.

Comment: A quick test you can do is copy and paste the API request in your browser and the JSON should be returned. I still get the "Gone" message when I use the API you posted: http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/5qtdkod0?apikey=z6vewKq5SXBcF6Q6L17sQEJ8gaYMou0C

Answer (score 0):

1) When you're making a jsfiddle, you need to add jQuery by clicking on the gear icon in the top right corner of the javascript box.

2) you're getting an undefined because the URL you are requesting is not returning a jsonp response. put it in your browser and see. The reason, I gather from the docs on that website, is because it requires an API key, and you are not sending an API key.

Read more about it [here](https://www.kimonolabs.com/apidocs).

Edit, after reading Barmar's comment, it looks like you're trying to send an API key, but it's not being sent becuase you're missing the ampersand before it. should be `/?...&apikey=...`

Comment: He's sending an API key with the `apikey=xxx` parameter. I suspect the web service simply doesn't suppose JSONP.

Comment: @Barmar, no, he's not. but now that you mention it i can see he was trying to.

Comment: I'm hoping that was just a copying error, but maybe not.